# Browser issues for web applications

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-5

I have installed IE8 on my system. I usually test my application on this browser, but the problem arises when i got to know that the client is using IE5. Now how can i test my application on IE5?

Comment: uninstall IE8 and then install IE5? as simple as that?

Comment: Who on earth still using IE5 ? You must punish them without testing your app in that :)

Comment: IE **5** ?  _Seriously?_  I would not, in any way, shape, or form, support a client on IE5. Or IE 6.  Even 7 would be questionable, since 9, 10, and 11 are available.

Comment: is there  any tools for that like PC emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use IEtester application for testing with IE5.5 and above. Just follow this image link to see the screen shot of this application.
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/uploads/IETester/ietester-0.3.png

Comment: Thank you ranjit  downloaded IEtester from http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage  but the application is not working

Comment: I don't know what's the problem.I think it may the problem of downloaded installer.I have used it.This application is look like a browser with tabs.Just type the url in the top box and go.Bye the bye,I'll give you another downloadable url.Some times it may work.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Browsers/IETester.shtml

Comment: There is a google chrome browser plugin available for testing IE in google chrome.Just follow this link in google chrome browser and click 'free button' and add it.You should read the warning from google chrome about third party plugins-it can read your browsing history like that. I think it's like a warning like facebook when we add the apps.I didn't have use it before.This is the link to that plugin

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/test-ie/eldlkpeoddgbmpjlnpfblfpgodnojfjl?hl=en